# How to change button text by verifying data are same or not when edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need one help.
I need to change button text according to some condition using Javascript/Jquery. I will explain my code below.

Here, when a user is selects the drop-down list, the 3 input field is filled with some value. the JavaScript code is given below.

```js
function setValue(){
  var arrField=[];
  if(document.getElementById('uinfo').value==1){
  document.getElementById('uname').value="Ram";
  document.getElementById('uemail').value="subhra@gmail.com";
  document.getElementById('ucity').value="cuttuck";
  arrField.push({'uname':document.getElementById('uname').value,'uemail':document.getElementById('uemail').value,'ucity':document.getElementById('ucity').value});
  }else{
    document.getElementById('uname').value="";
  document.getElementById('uemail').value="";
  document.getElementById('ucity').value="";
  var arrField=[];
  } 
  }
```

```html
   

 <select onchange="setValue();" id="uinfo">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">User Info</option>
      </select>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uemail"/>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">City</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="ucity"  />
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkAllValue();">
        <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Add
      </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkAll();">
        <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Check
      </button>
```

Here I need that when a user will click on the `Check` button it will check for the original value after the drop down select if all are as it was then the `Add` button text will remain as `Add`.
If any field value has changed after selecting that button text will change to `Update`. 
Please help me.

Comment: you mean if user change value then button will change to UPDATE?

Comment: Yes,Check my updated post again.Here user will click on check button and if all  field value are same after selecting drop down the `add` button will remain same .If user will change any field value and click on check button the `Add` button will change to update.

Comment: show your `checkAll` function.

Comment: Actually i need that single `if...else` condition inside `checkAll` function to change button text.

Comment: @subhra check my answer!

Comment: @subhra I've edited my answer based on your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```js
//Object, key based on select options
var popData= {
  'user-info': 
  {uname: 'User1', uemail: 'user1@test.com', ucity: 'user city'}
  ,
  'emp-info': 
  {uname: 'Emp1', uemail: 'emp1@test.com', ucity: 'emp city'}
};
//Select change that will update values
$('#uinfo').change(function(){
  $.each(popData[$(this).val()], function( i, val ) {
    $('#'+i).val(val);
  });
});
//When input change check based on the conditions
$('button.check').click(function(){
  //Check if any changes in the fields
  if(
    popData[$('#uinfo').val()].uname != $('#uname').val() ||
    popData[$('#uinfo').val()].uemail != $('#uemail').val() ||     popData[$('#uinfo').val()].ucity != $('#ucity').val()
    )
  {
    $('button.add').text('Update');
  }
  //Check if no changes in the fields
  else if(popData[$('#uinfo').val()].uname == $('#uname').val() &&
    popData[$('#uinfo').val()].uemail == $('#uemail').val() &&     popData[$('#uinfo').val()].ucity == $('#ucity').val())
  {
      $('button.add').text('Add');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="uinfo">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="user-info">User Info</option>
    <option value="emp-info">Emp Info</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uemail"/>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">City</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="ucity"  />
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn check">
    <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Check
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add">
    <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Add
  </button>
```

Comment: @ Loading.. :This is not my requirement.Please read my post again.

Comment: @subhra: From where these values will be check to verify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
  function setValue(){
      var arrField=[];
      if(document.getElementById('uinfo').value==1){
      document.getElementById('uname').value="Ram";
      document.getElementById('uemail').value="subhra@gmail.com";
      document.getElementById('ucity').value="cuttuck";
      arrField.push({'uname':document.getElementById('uname').value,'uemail':document.getElementById('uemail').value,'ucity':document.getElementById('ucity').value});
      }else{
        document.getElementById('uname').value="";
      document.getElementById('uemail').value="";
      document.getElementById('ucity').value="";
      var arrField=[];
      } 
      }
function checkAll(){
  var uname = $('#uname').val();
  var email = $('#uemail').val();
  var city = $('#ucity').val();
var count = 0;
if(uname!='Ram')
  {
   count++; 
   }
 else if(email!='subhra@gmail.com')
     {
   count++; 
   }
  else if(city!='cuttuck')
      {
   count++; 
   }
  if(count>0)
    {
      $('#add').text('UPDATE');
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="setValue();" id="uinfo">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">User Info</option>
          </select>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uemail"/>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label">City</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="ucity"  />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
          </div>
          <button  id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkAllValue();">
            <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Add
          </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkAll();">
            <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Check
          </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrField = new Array();

function setValue() {

  if (document.getElementById('uinfo').value == 1) {
    document.getElementById('uname').value = "Ram";
    document.getElementById('uemail').value = "subhra@gmail.com";
    document.getElementById('ucity').value = "cuttuck";
    arrField.push({
      'uname': document.getElementById('uname').value,
      'uemail': document.getElementById('uemail').value,
      'ucity': document.getElementById('ucity').value
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('uname').value = "";
    document.getElementById('uemail').value = "";
    document.getElementById('ucity').value = "";
    arrField = [];
  }

  $('#Save').text('Add');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#uname, #uemail, #ucity').change(function() {

    if (arrField[0].uname == $('#uname').val() && arrField[0].uemail == $('#uemail').val() && arrField[0].ucity == $('#ucity').val())
      $('#Save').text('Add');
    else
      $('#Save').text('Update');


  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="setValue();" id="uinfo">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">User Info</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uname" />
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="uemail" />
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label">City</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="ucity" />
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkAllValue();" id="Save">
  <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Add
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The (additional) jQuery code you're looking for would be something like this. Note that I added the class "changebtn" to the target button to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Save original value when document is ready
  var original = $("#uinfo").val();

  // Update Button when current value is different 
  // from original as the selection changes
  $("#uinfo").on("change", function(){
    if ($(this).val() != original) {
      $(".changebtn").html("Update");
    } else {
      // Reset Button when User switches back to original
      $(".changebtn").html("Add");
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0yj5y5sb/2/